# How to change window size UWP in Hololens?

Tags: uwp, resize, window

I want to set a window size for my app once. Since it is bigger than the default window, I could do it either by setting a minimum size, or by changing the size myself to that minimum during the launch.

I have tried

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(1200, 900);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(800, 600));
```

and this

```
float DPI = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

var desiredSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(((float)800 * 96.0f / DPI), ((float)600 * 96.0f / DPI));

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = desiredSize;

Window.Current.Activate();

bool result = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(desiredSize);
```

But none work. What am I missing?